# Get multiple values from data

Tags: python, json, database, api

How do I get multiple items from a database? For example, I have a database

```
"pets": [
{
"type": "BEE"
"level": "56"
},
{
"type": "HORSE"
"level": "90
}
```

Here, I want to get the "type". I want the response to be BEE, HORSE. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you really have an actual database? Or are you just storing this list somewhere?

Comment: I am getting the information from a JSON API website. I have listed the information here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple list comprehension for the same

```
pets = {} #your data
types = [item.get("type", None) for item in pets]
```